# How to make a Python Context Manager wrap a piece of code and execute it as a batch?

Tags: python

Is it possible in python to store functions that would have been executed?

More specifically, would it be possible to create that using a context manager? I've seen once a context manager that would retry all the wrapped code inside, but I could not figure out how to do that.

For instance, let's say I have

```
def print():
  print("printed")
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
with StopFunctionsExecution() as functions_executed:
   print()
   print()
   print()
   # So far, nothing in console
   functions_executed.run_all()  #  or on __exit__
   # All 3 printed in console
```

Comment: You can already do that with an ordinary function. Why do you need a context manager?

Comment: `def StopFunctionsExecutions(): print(); print(); print()`, followed by `StopFunctionsExecutions()`.

Comment: Could you rephrase that without re-using the `print` variable name to recursively/accidentally call itself?

Comment: BTW: If all you want to do is to execute some code at some point, you just put that code in a function. Note that Python not just allows local function definitions, it encourages them even by supporting closures! In any case, I believe you're describing a so-called "XY problem" (research that term!), so maybe you want to take a step back and completely rewrite your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "schedule" the execution of regular code instead of executing it right away because that would require changes to how that code is interpreted -- i.e. changes to the interpreter.

But you can change *when* the interpreter gets to execute that code:

```
def batch(*args):
    for fn, *args_ in args:
        fn.__call__(*args_)

def foo():
    print("blah")
    print("blar")
    print("xyzzy")

batch_list = ((print, "foo"),(print, "bar"), (print, "baz"), (foo,))

<somewhere later>
batch(*batch_list)
```

This is the way how calls are scheduled for execution elsewhere in `threading` and `multiprocessing` -- by passing the function and its arguments separately.